# Reading Python List in a Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a project for Python and the list "lst" is not initializing properly. I should be able to initialize a list, run a method that adds values to the list and then use the list back in the main program. However, the list just becomes blank when I'm back in the main program.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
lst = [ ]

def readList(infile, lst):
    for line in infile:
        lst = line.strip().split()
    print(lst)

file_name = input("Input File Name: ")

file = open(file_name)

readList(file, lst)

print(lst)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function [doesn't *mutate* `lst`, it **rebinds** it.](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) The bound value is lost when the function exits, so you get nothing.

```
lst.append(line.strip().split())
```

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I was doing wrong. Thanks! Silly question now... it's creating a list of a list. How can I remove the double list?

Comment: [Extend instead of appending.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)